# How can I do a multi level ORDER BY where rows with specific values will get preference?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample table

```
+------+--------+------------------+
| Code |  City  |       Role       |
+------+--------+------------------+
|    1 | Mumbai | Designer         |
|    2 | Mumbai | Designer         |
|    3 | Delhi  | Designer         |
|    4 | Delhi  | Project Manager  |
|    5 | Mumbai | Project Manager  |
|    6 | Pune   | Designer         |
|    7 | London | Network Engineer |
+------+--------+------------------+
```

Level 1 sort will be on City field - First Delhi, then Mumbai then anything else. 
Level 2 sort will be on Role field - First Project Manager, then Designer, then anything else.

Output after the sort should be

```
+------+--------+------------------+
| Code |  City  |       Role       |
+------+--------+------------------+
|    4 | Delhi  | Project Manager  |
|    3 | Delhi  | Designer         |
|    5 | Mumbai | Project Manager  |
|    1 | Mumbai | Designer         |
|    2 | Mumbai | Designer         |
|    6 | Pune   | Designer         |
|    7 | London | Network Engineer |
+------+--------+------------------+
```

Comment: Use a `case` expression in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, one method is:

```
order by (case when city = 'Delhi' then 1
               when city = 'Mumbai' then 2
               else 3
          end),
         city,
         (case when role = 'Project Manager' then 1
               when role = 'Designer' then 2
               else 3
          end)
```

A shorter, but somewhat enigmatic method uses:

```
order by field(city, 'Mumbai', 'Delhi') desc,
         city,
         field(role, 'Designer', 'Project Manager') desc
```

`field()` returns `0` when there is no match.  So the arguments are in reverse order relative to how you want them searched.  The `desc` then puts them in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY (case when City = 'Delhi' then 1
              when City = 'Mumbai' then 2
              else 3
         end asc),
         (case when role = 'Project Manager' then 1
              when City = 'Designer' then 2
              else 3
         end asc)
```